# Reg Ex: Repeating Patterns that match different values

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to re-use regex groups for example:

```
(?<var>[A-Za-z](\d*\w*)*)
```

Matches most variable names e.g. `abc`, `abc123`, `abc_123`, `abc_123_abc` and so on.

Is there a way I could re-use this group without typing the whole pattern again?

---

For example if I wanted to create a regex to match the below string:

```
abc_123 AS xyz_89
```

I would need to create a reg ex like:

```
^([A-Za-z](\d*\w*)*)( AS )([A-Za-z](\d*\w*)*)$
```

And to match something like:

```
abc_123.def_456 AS xyz_89
```

I would need to use the same pattern 3 times.

It would seem more efficient to be able to refer back to the first group so I'm not repeating regex logic. I've read about back referencing but it seems like they are meant for matching the same **value** rather than general pattern.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Backreferencing only returns what was _captured_ in a previous portion of the regex.  It doesn't actually synthesize any new information.

Comment: By the way `(\d*\w*)*` is opening the gates to catastrophic backtracking hell.

Comment: @anubhava Java currently

Comment: @SebastianProske Im open to better ways of achieving the same thing :)

Comment: Just build the pattern dynamically: `String t = "part1"; String s = "part2"; String pattern = t + s + "something here" + t;`

Comment: `[A-Za-z]\w*` would be the same. Sadly there is no support for recursion in java regex.

Answer (score 2):

In **php**, the recursing sub pattern works:

```
^([A-Za-z](?:\d*\w*)*)( AS )(?1)
```

The above regex will match:

```
abc_123 AS xyz_89
```

Explanation:

1. `([A-Za-z](?:\d*\w*)*)` Taken from your example and marked as group 1
2. `( AS )` taken from your example, which remains as it is
3. `(?1)` is a recursing sub pattern of the first group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZ1mCQ/3)

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman Yes, I have added the java tag. Regex questions without a language/tool/dialect tag are barely answerable, especially if they depend on features that are only available in some flavours. This is the reason anubhava asked for clarification in a comment.

Comment: @SebastianProske oh ok got that now :|